# Change the button style on MediaRouteControllerDialog

Tags: chromecast, google-cast

I would like to change the disconnect button color and maybe other things on the MediaRouteControllerDialog shown when the user presses on the cast icon and they are already connected.

I'm already using a custom media control view but that doesn't seem to include the disconnect button.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just find the view you want to modify and do it that way.

On the `onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)` method do the following:

```
    Button disconnectButton =   (Button)findViewById(R.id.media_route_disconnect_button);
```